# installing libsocket-perl, apt-get searches for wrong filename extension, gets 404

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt

I've been having trouble installing a package for a number of days now and can't find the solution anywhere, though I have been able to figure out more exactly what's going wrong. It appears that apt-get or aptitude appends an incorrect extension to the file when searching for a specific dependency package `libsocket-perl` in the archive mirror.

Looking through the archive, I can find many versions of the package:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libsocket-perl/

```
libsocket-perl_2.014-1+b2_s390x.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1.debian.tar.xz
libsocket-perl_2.014-1.dsc
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_amd64.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_armel.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_armhf.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_i386.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_kfreebsd-amd64.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_kfreebsd-i386.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_mips.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_mipsel.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014-1_powerpc.deb
libsocket-perl_2.014.orig.tar.gz
...
```

but when apt-get or aptitude attempt to get and install it, I get this error thrown:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libsocket-perl/libsocket-perl_2.014-1+b1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

The `+b1_amd64.deb` extension is not to be found on the archive.

Now I don't really understand why I need a `+b1` version of the package or why it isn't available on the archive. Is there a way that I can get the package manager to search for an available version that would do instead?

Comment: What version of Debian? Include the output of `apt-cache policy libsocket-perl` in the question, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command `apt-cache` to find what versions of a give package are available:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg libsocket-perl
```

And then based on that output, steer `apt-get` into picking a particular version like so:

```
$ apt-get install <package name>=<version>
```

For example:

```
$ apt-get install libsocket-perl=2.014-1_amd64
```

You can do this with an `update` as well.

```
$ apt-get update libsocket-perl=2.014-1_amd64
```

#### Why the error?

It looks like a packaging error to me, nothing more.